# Magento showing different product quantities on different pages

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We have a Magento site running on version 1.7.0 on the Argento theme that seems to be having intermittent issues with products not appearing. This appears to happen on certain pages and not others.

For example, if you add a product from the homepage or single category pages, it will show immediately as being part of the cart (note, Argento uses AjaxPro for the cart). However, once you navigate to another page, say "My Cart" or "Checkout" the total will show as zero. Doing a hard-refresh on the browser will update the total.

Additionally, if you open the Chrome Dev tools, navigate to "Network" and then check "disable cache" everything runs perfectly.

Things we have tried to resolve this:

- Flushing/Clearing/Disabling the Magento cache. Seems to make things slightly better but doesn't clear up the issue.
- x-cache-control meta tag. Same as above, issue seems to be less frequent but still definitely appearing.
- Turn off AjaxPro. Our initial belief was that this plugin was causing issues, but turning it off has no effect.
- Re-Index. Has no effect.
- Added `$.ajaxSetup({"cache" : false})` at the top of our scripts. This also has no effect.

Any advice or tips on where to look next would be appreciated.

Comment: From what I'm hearing you're having problems with cached pages/routes that are stale. Data has changed but the cached page serves out-of-date pages. If so look into holepunching blocks you want to stay dynamic at all times: http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/magento-tutorials/mini-tutorial-hole-punching-configurable-product-options/

Comment: @VladimirRamik Thank you - would this still be an issue when the cache is disabled?

Comment: Possibly not but performance would take a urge hit. Disable cache and confirm it to be the culprit.

Comment: @VladimirRamik We actually disabled the cache as one of the initial debugging steps and had no luck.

Comment: Turn on template hints. Find the template/block that renders the mini cart object. Print what code outputs the cart. Should be something like...     $oQuote         = Mage::getModel( 'checkout/cart' )->getQuote()
    $oCartItems     = $oQuote->getAllItems(); My guess is that you might be potentially using a stale cart method that doesn't get update until a full page reload.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that our hosting provider had set up the installation with the sessions stored in memcache. We switched this over to file storage in our local.xml and it fixed the issue.